# convert List[String] into Map[String,String]

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

Anyone help me to convert list of strings into Map by indexes: (0,1) as key-value pair and index(2,3) as 2nd pair and index(3,4) as 3rd pair.

Example: `List("asd","fgh","qwe","tyu")` into `Map("asd"->"fgh", "qwe"->"tyu")`

Comment: if there is odd number and repeated elements, no problem i just want the result as map by following indexes (0,1) as key value pair and (2,3) index as key value pair .

Comment: So, if odd, the last string in the `List` should be ignored and not included in the `Map` result?

Comment: the odd string should be considered but it should show the odd string -> " "(null value)

Comment: An empty string, `""`, is not a `null` value.

Comment: for an odd number i want that as empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using three standard library methods:

```
val list = List("asd","fgh","qwe","tyu")

list
  .grouped(2) // Group elements in pairs
  .map {      // Convert pairs to tuples
    case a :: b :: Nil => a -> b   // Normal values to tuple
    case a :: Nil      => a -> ""  // Final value if list size is odd
  }
  .toMap // Convert List[(A, B)] to Map[A,B]
```

Since you are creating a `Map`, if the same even value appears more than once there will be duplicate keys, and only the final pair will be in the resulting `Map`.

(If you are new to Scala, the syntax `a -> b` is another way of creating a tuple `(a, b)`, and can be used in cases like this to make it clear that there is a key-value relationship between values in a pair)